# how to fetch the smallest value in mysql database by comparing it with default value if value does not given in php form

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    O_Id int(primary key),
    OrderNo varchar default 'no',
    P_Id varchar default 'no',
    rate varchar DEFAULT 'no' 
)
```

in this case i have set default value as 'no'.even if i did not give a  value in my php form it should take the value as no.

now i want to compare the smallest value in the row i have 3 attributes to which i have to compare and which value is the smallest then i have to display it.

but the problem is when i am not giving the value in php form it is not taking the default value and not comparing with other values which actually exist.

finally,i want to compare the values with other values and should fetch the smallest value in the row even i am giving value in my php form how to make it happen?? i need the sql query to execute the above context.

Comment: can you dump here some rows of table and expected result.?

Comment: # Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Extra 
 1 artnoPrimary varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No
 2 shankar varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no 
 3 behru varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no
 4 bava varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no
 5 bavavkc varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no  
 6 ansari varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no 
 7 ff varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No no 

 8 rh varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  No    no

Comment: i need to fetch which value is the smallest.i need to compare value the issue is that i cant fetch value if any one of the attribute is empty if and only if all the arributes are fill the i can get the smallest value.i need to get the smallest value even if some attribute do not have value.

Comment: my expectation is i need to compare and fetch the value even some of the attribute is not filled in php form that is those values are  null in mysql database.how to do it please help me..

Comment: in the above given tabel if i have given values for 7 attribute among 8.now what i need is i need to get the smallest value among the 7 which i have given the values.the issue is if any one of the attribute is not filled in php form then it is not fetching the smallest value.